# Section header view that changes visibility with scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

Section header view that changes visibility with scroll

I have a tableview that features section headers, I’m able to access the section header views when they appear  by adding a UIView property and assigning it to each section header view:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
if (section != 0) {
NSDictionary *post = [items objectAtIndex:section - 1];
HeaderView *view = [[HeaderView alloc] initWithClient:_client andPost:post];
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.headerView = view;
return view;
} else {
return nil;
}
}
```

I want the section header to have a an alpha of 0 (translucent) from the bottom of the cell and gradually reach an alpha of 1 (be visible) as the user scrolls to the top of the cell. How would I go about doing this?